# Inline tag not executing in an asp.net master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

This really should be so very simple...

I have an asp.net master page which is working as expected. It includes some asp: tags without any problems.

The master page also includes the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css?v=<%=variableName%>" />
```

which is not executing. The output HTML has this as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css?v=&lt;%=variableName%>" />
```

I do not work in asp.net very much so hopefully I have missed something super simple. Any suggesions on how to stop my inline asp tags from being HTML-encoded?

Many thanks.

**EDIT**

So it just gets sillier

This works: `href="css/main.css?v=<%:"variableName"%>"` and outputs `href="css/main.css?v=variableName"`

However this doesn't: `href="css/main.css?v=<%:variableName%>"` and outputs `href="css/main.css?v=&lt;%:variableName%>"`

Seriously I never thought I would say it but PHP makes WAYYY more sense!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one

**UPDATE:**  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=<%="'css/main.css?v="+"34'"%> />`

Comment: I see what you're aiming for, but that gives href="&lt;%=&quot;css/main.css?v=&quot;+variableName%>" (and yes I did change the quotes, this is what asp.net generated)

Comment: Sorry for that. Quotation were placed wrong. Answer is updated.

Comment: OK the update makes it, thanks for the help. I'm really surprised at how weak this is and can't help feeling it's Microsoft over-compensating for web development beginners. If I use inline tags they should execute regardless of whether they're quoted or not. If I want to use <% in an HTML attribute I will escape it myself. Sheesh...

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%="css/main.css?v="+"34"%>" /> also works for me, vs <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css?v=<%=34%>" />